# If $E_1\subset E_2$, then $\overline E_1\subset\overline E_2$

Tags: real-analysis

> **Definitions:** Let $E$ be any set of real numbers and let $E'$ denote the set of all accumulation points of $E$. Then the set
>   $$\overline E=E\cup E'$$ is called the *closure* of the set $E$.

Show that if $E_1\subset E_2$, then $\overline E_1\subset\overline E_2$.

**My attempt:**

We need to prove that if $x\in\overline E_1$, then $x\in\overline E_2$.

Let $x\in\overline E_1$

$\implies x\in E_1\cup E_1'$

$\implies x\in E_1$ or $x\in E_1'$

If $x\in E_1$, then $x\in E_2\implies x\in E_2\cup E_2'\implies x\in\overline E_2$ and we are done.

But what if  $x\in E_1'$? What property of accumulation points do I use to prove that $x\in\overline E_2$?

Comment: Just note that $E'_{1}\subset E'_{2}$.

Comment: If $x$ is an accumulation point of $E_1$ then there are points of $E_1$ in any neighbourhood. Those are also points of $E_2$, therefore $x$ is also an accumulation point of $E_2$.

Comment: you have to use the definition of "accumulation points"

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x\in E_1'$, this means that every open set containing $x$ intersects $E_1$. But then every open set containing $x$ intersects $E_2$, we conclude $x\in E_2'$, and so $x\in \overline E_2$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x \in \overline{E}_1$.

**Case 1:** $x \in E_1$.

Then $x \in E_2$, so $x \in \overline{E}_2$.

**Case 2:** $x \notin E_1$, but $x$ is an accumulation point of $E_1$.

Then there are points of $E_1$ in any neighborhood of $x$. All these points are also in $E_2$, so there are points of $E_2$ in any neighborhood of $x$. Thus, $x \in \overline{E}_2$.